# Need some explanation to understand how Grails works

Tags: grails

I'm new to Grails, some things are still vague for me.

I want to create a Twitter-like app. As a user has both a followers and a following groups, I've created a `GroupMyTwitter` domain.

What I don't understand, is the logic behind this. My `GroupMyTwitter` domain is like this :

```
class GroupMyTwitter
{
    String name;

    static constraints = { name blank : false; }

    static hasMany = [users:UserMyTwitter];
    static belongsTo = [owner:UserMyTwitter];
}
```

Then every time I create a user I also create two groups associated to him :

```
GroupMyTwitter followers = new GroupMyTwitter (
    name:"followers",
    owner: user).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
// And same for followings
```

Now I simply wonder... how can I access these groups to get the followers/ings count, add or delete some?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please add the content of `UserMyTwitter`?

Comment: Yes, but I think the relevant part is that my UserMyTwitter domain has this property : `static hasMany = [groupes:GroupCwitter];`. So if I do `user.groupes.size()` I correctly get 2 (followers and followings), but how can I access these groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` variables gorm automatically creates some instance fields for you:

```
 static hasMany = [users:UserMyTwitter];
```

This will create a field `users` of type [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) inside `GroupMyTwitter`.
You can access this `Set` like any other field:

```
followers.users.add(userA)    // add a user
followers.users.remove(userB) // remove a user
followers.users.size()        // number of users

// don't forget to save the group after you modfied the `users` collection:
followers.save(failOnError: true)
```

Depending on your needs it might be useful to use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of a `Set`:

```
class GroupMyTwitter {
   List users
   static hasMany = [users:UserMyTwitter];
   ...
}
```

This causes Gorm to use a `List` for the `users` collection instead of a `Set`.

A `List` has a defined order and allows you to access certain elements by index:

```
UserMyTwitter user = followers.users[4] // get the 5th user
```